# Is running docker-compose not supported in BitBucket?

Tags: bitbucket, docker-compose

**Aim**

The aim is to run docker-compose in BitBucket pipelines

**Attempt**

*bitbucket-pipelines.yml*

```
image: docker/compose:1.12.0

pipelines:
  default:
    - step:
        script:
          - docker-compose up --build
```

**Outcome**

```
The Docker Engine version is less than the minimum required by Compose.
Your current project requires a Docker Engine of version 1.13.0 or greater.
```

**Discussion**

According to [this](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Bitbucket-questions/Docker-compose-and-pipelines/qaq-p/67913) post it is not supported?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here is my solution: (bitbucket-pipelines.yml)

```
pipelines:
  default:
    - step:
        script:
          - export DOCKER_COMPOSE_VERSION=1.18.0
          - export DOCKER_COMPOSE_URL=https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/${DOCKER_COMPOSE_VERSION}/docker-compose-$(uname -s)-$(uname -m)
          - curl -L $DOCKER_COMPOSE_URL > docker-compose
          - chmod +x docker-compose
          - mv docker-compose /usr/local/bin
          - docker-compose build --force-rm --no-cache --pull
```

Answer (score 6):

We are less likely to see support of native docker-compose integration because pipelines API is a custom implementation of similar functionality, and also because possible security issues, but looks like more features are currently in development to implement more docker-compose-like features in [this](https://bitbucket.org/site/master/issues/12757/ability-to-run-multiple-docker-containers) open issue.

UPDATE: added support for multi-container pipelines, as described in [documentation](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/service-containers-for-bitbucket-pipelines-874786688.html)

Answer (score 3):

I managed to use docker-compose to push images to a remote host by using the following image.

[tmaier/docker-compose:latest](https://hub.docker.com/r/tmaier/docker-compose/)

This is the basic [docker image](https://hub.docker.com/r/_/docker/) with docker-compose installed.

My `bitbucket-pipelines.yml` looks like this:

```
- step:
    image: tmaier/docker-compose:latest
    script:
        - (umask  077 ; echo $DOCKER_PRIVATE_KEY | base64 -d > ./keys/key.pem)
        - export DOCKER_CERT_PATH=./keys/
        - export DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY="1"
        - export DOCKER_HOST=tcp://<DOCKER_HOST_IP>:2376
        - docker login --username $DOCKER_HUB_USERNAME --password $DOCKER_HUB_PASSWORD
        - docker-compose up -d <service>
```

I have checked-in in my repo the `ca.pem` and `cert.pem` needed by docker-compose in the `keys` directory. The private key is saved base64encoded, as a secure variable in Bitbucket pipelines environment variables, so I just decode it and paste it to `keys/key.pem` in the pipeline as the first step.

Keep in mind that i used `docker login` after setting the enviroment variables for the remote host.

Answer (score 2):

**bitbucket-pipelines.yml**

```
image: python:3.8.1

pipelines:
  branches:
    "**":
      - step:
          name: Build
          services:
            - docker
          caches:
            - docker
            - pip
          script:
            - pip install docker-compose
            - docker network create dockernet
            - docker-compose build

definitions:
  services:
    docker:
      memory: 2048
```